# Entity Framework DbContext.SaveChanges() returning one more int than I expected

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, dbcontext

I am trying to debug, or figure out what entity framework is doing here during my inserts. Here is my job context modelbuilder, where I am working with Jobs, logs and user entities

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new JobMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new LogMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new UserMap());
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
```

My Job entity below has two navigation properties to the other entities. However, the User and Log class do not have a navigation property back to the job because that would not make sense in my program even though they are setup in the DB (and the user does not have a navigation back to the log)

```
public class Job: BaseEntity
{
    // ... other properties of type string, int, DateTime etc.

    public int UserId { get; set }
    public User Owner { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Log> Logs{ get; private set; }
}


public class Log: BaseEntity
{
    // ... other properties of type string, int, DateTime etc.

    public int UserId { get; set }
    public User Owner { get; set; }
}
```

In my mapping class, the job class is the only class that has the relationship defined in the fluent API. The log and user class have no relationships setup.

```
    public JobMap()
    {
        // .. table and column mappings here

        // Relationships

        this.HasRequired(t => t.Owner)

        this.HasMany(t => t.Logs)
            .WithRequired()
            .Map(t => t.MapKey("JobId"));
    }
```

When I go to create a new Job, I specifically add a log and user to the job class and call my generic repository for the job entity.

```
    public T InsertOrUpdate<T>(T entity) where T : BaseEntity
    {
        if (entity.Id == default(int))
        {
            this.Entry<T>(entity).State = EntityState.Added;
        }
        else
        {
            this.Set<T>().Add(entity);
            this.Entry<T>(entity).State = StateMapper.ConvertState(entity.State);
        }

        return entity;
    }
```

When I call `DbContext.SaveChanges`, I check the ChangeTracker and the job is marked as added, the log is marked as added and the user is marked as unchanged (because the user exists), however, SaveChanges returns 3 and not 2 like I expected. Am I doing something wrong in my setup? Even looking at SQL profiler I see two insert queries

```
exec sp_executesql N'INSERT [dbo].[Job]([UserId], [RequestDateTime], [DueDate],[Reason]    VALUES (@0, @1, @2, @3)
SELECT [JobId]
FROM [dbo].[Job]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND [JobId] = scope_identity()',N'@0 nvarchar(20),@1 datetime2(7),@2 datetime2(7),@3 nvarchar(10)',@0=N'C123',@1='2014-06-07 09:28:00.7538457',@2='2014-06-14 00:00:00',@3=N'klj''

exec sp_executesql N'INSERT [dbo].[Log]([ChangedByUserId], [ChangedDateTime], [Reason] , [JobId])
VALUES (@0, @1, @2, @3)
SELECT [LogId]
FROM [dbo].[Log]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND [LogId] = scope_identity()',N'@0 nvarchar(20),@1 datetime2(7),@2 nvarchar(200),@3 int',@0=N'C123',@1='2014-06-07 09:28:00.7538457',@2=N'Job Created',@3=128
```

**EDIT**

even if the user is set to Null, both of those queries are executed and 3 is returned, so I must have something wrong in my setup. If the user is set to the Added State, then SaveChanges returns 4?

Comment: Does one of the tables have an insert trigger?

Comment: nope. I just checked that to make sure

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert by any means with entity framework, but I wanted to post my findings in case this tripped aynone else up. This line of code was making `SaveChanges()` return one more `int` than I expected everytime.

```
this.HasMany(t => t.Logs)
    .WithRequired()
    .Map(t => t.MapKey("JobId"));
```

i removed this mapping and put a foreign key in the log class and `SaveChanges()` returned the number I expected. So that particular mapping must be doing something extra with the relationship that I am not sure about right now